# How to know which statistical model to use for categorical data?

Tags: regression, correlation, multiple-regression, python, scikit-learn

I'm new to statistical analysis.

I'm trying to conduct an analysis of datapoints and possible correlations between them using Python's sci-kit learn library.

My data is  categorical.

For example, a question would be posed as -

'What race are you?

1 - Black/African American
2- White
3 - Asian 
4- Hispanic '

'How much money do you make'
1- 10,000 - 30,000
2 - 30,000 - 60,000
3 - 60,000 - 90,000
4 - 90,000 - 125,000

And for this data I have about 50 responses: 10 White, 15 Black , 10 Asian, 15 Hispanic.

I want to use a specific response for further analysis. For example, if I want to look at a possible  correlation between responding as white and the responses for 'How much money you make'. White would be my independent variable, and the amount made would be my dependent variable.

What statistical method should I use in order to analyze this type of data?

Comment: Alan Agresti, *Introduction to Categorical Data Analysis* is a great place to start.

Comment: too broad? and if possible please revise your title to be more specific